# implementation of scala function name.exists(_.isUpper) in Java (Programming in scala)

Tags: java, scala

```
// scala code
    val nameHasUpperCase = name.exists(_.isUpperCase)
```

> In principle, such control abstractions are possible in Java as well.
>   You’d need to define an interface that contains a method with the
>   abstracted functionality. For instance, if you wanted to support
>   querying over strings, you might invent an interface, named
>   CharacterProperty, which has just one method, hasProperty: // this is
>   Java

`interface CharacterProperty { boolean hasProperty(char ch); }`

> With that interface you could formulate a method exists in Java: It
>   takes a string and CharacterProperty and returns true if there’s a
>   character in the string that satisfies the property. You could then
>   invoke exists as follows:

```
//this is Java
 exists(name, new CharacterProperty() {
    public boolean hasProperty(char ch) { 
      return Character.isUpperCase(ch); }
 });
```

I can not get this case runnable. How to interpret the author's words and implement this in Java language with interface? Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, in Java 8 you can almost do it as nicely as in Scala:

`name.chars().anyMatch(Character::isUpperCase)`

Before Java 8, there was no way to do method abstraction (introduced by lambdas and method references), so you had to write wrapper classes for single-function tests, making it awkward and cumbersome. Hence the remark that nobody really does it.

The code would probably go like this:

```
public boolean exists(String str, CharacterProperty prop) {
    return str.chars().anyMatch(prop::hasProperty);
}
```

Comment: Good, This book is published in 2011, While Java8 came in 2014. Whether there is  some other answers for this question?